# Rationalization of a fraction

Tags: fractions, radicals

Can someone please explain how i can rationalize the fraction $\frac{2 +\sqrt{3}}{(2-\sqrt{3})^3}$ so that i obtain an answer that has an exponent of 6. I basically need to compare this value with $\dfrac{(10)^6}{(3)^6}$ to see which is greater. Thanks in advance for helping out!

Comment: Welcome to math stack, what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Multiply numerator and denominator with $$(2+\sqrt{3})^3$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{(2-\sqrt{3})^3}&=\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{(2-\sqrt{3})^3}\cdot\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^3}{(2+\sqrt{3})^3}\\
&=\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^4}{(2^2-3)^3}\\
&=\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^4}{1}\\
&=(2+\sqrt{3})^4
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply top and bottom of your fraction by $(2+\sqrt{3})^3$ and obtain $(2+\sqrt{3})^4$ since $(2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3})=1$